# Best way for validate Bean in Spring+Jersey rest api

Tags: spring, rest, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I want to validate bean in rest api. In Spring mvc application we can use BindingResult for validate bean. But when We make rest application in spring , i am not able validate bean with the help BindingResult. I knew that we can validate bean in rest api using The JSR 303 . But my want to know what is best practice for validate a bean in spring rest application and this bean created in application.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your bean validation? If yes, can you please share?